# Return rows with last appearance of an id

Tags: r

I have a log table of entries in the following format:

```
timestamp,id,enabled
2014-11-07 17:16:38,1,TRUE
2014-11-07 17:44:30,2,TRUE
2014-11-07 18:07:13,2,FALSE
2014-11-07 18:11:48,1,TRUE
```

I want to return the last row where each particular id appears. So in the case above, the output would be:

```
2014-11-07 18:07:13,2,FALSE
2014-11-07 18:11:48,1,TRUE
```

How can I do that in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this. Here's a method using the `dplyr` package, assuming your data frame is called `dat`:

```
library(dplyr) 

dat %>% group_by(id) %>%
  slice(length(id))  # This selects the last row for a given ID

                 date id enabled
1 2014-11-07 18:11:48  1    TRUE
2 2014-11-07 18:07:13  2   FALSE
```

If you want to select the last row based on some ordering variable, like `date` in this case, then order by date first before slicing:

```
# First, convert date string to date format
library(lubridate)
dat$date = ymd_hms(dat$date)

dat %>% group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  slice(length(id))
```

**UPDATE:** Or, if you're ever code-golfing with @BenBolker and need to shave a  few characters off your score:

```
dat %>% group_by(id) %>%
  slice(n())
```

Comment: would `tail(1)` work instead of `slice(length(id))` ?

Comment: `tail` doesn't seem to honor the grouping variable, so you need to wrap it in `do`: `dat %>% group_by(id) %>% do(tail(.,1))`

Comment: still reduces the code from 17 to 13 characters (we're golfing, right?)

Comment: Heh, heh. Well played.

Answer (score 2):

Just couple of solutions without loading any packages

```
x <- read.csv(textConnection("timestamp,id,enabled                                                                                                                                                                                            
2014-11-07 17:16:38,1,TRUE                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
2014-11-07 17:44:30,2,TRUE                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
2014-11-07 18:07:13,2,FALSE                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
2014-11-07 18:11:48,1,TRUE"),header = TRUE,stringsAsFactors =FALSE)

# Solution 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
aggregate(x,by=list(x$id),FUN=function(x){tail(x,1)})

# Solution 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
data.frame(do.call('rbind',as.list(by(x,x$id,tail,1))),
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution in `plyr` is particularly compact (although probably slower than `dplyr`):

```
library("plyr")
ddply(dat,"id",tail,1)
```